# Using Cat to merge Files, ignoring the last Byte of each file

Tags: unix

I have written a rudimentary HTTP downloader that downloads parts of a file and stores them in temporary, partial files in a directory.

I can use

```
cat * > outputfilename
```

To concatenate the partial files together as their order is given by the individual filenames.

However.

The range of each file is something like:

```
File 1: 0 - 1000
File 2: 1000 - 2000
File 3: 2000 - 3000
```

For a file that is 3000 bytes in size. i.e. Last Byte overlaps of first byte.

The cat command duplicates the overlapping bytes into a new file.

Specifically, We can see this with images looking *wrong*

i.e:

(just using an image from imgur) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyofe.jpg

Renders with 1/(the number of partial files) of the image correctly.

[image: Sorry for the quality; upload size restrictions]

To note: The original image is 250 KB.

The concatenated image is 287 KB.

I will be implementing this in C99, Unix as a method that calls exec.

I'm not sure where to upload the partial files to assist w/ stackoverflow.

Comment: You might be able to just do this with head or similar if you know the exact byte count

Comment: `the overlapping bytes` - which bytes are overlapping? Ach, ok then. Ach so the last byte from file1 is overlapping with the first byte of file2? I think you can use `truncate` after each `cat` to remove last byte from file. So `cat file >> output` then remove last byte `truncate -s $(($(wc -b <output) - 1 )) output` and `cat second_file >> output` and `truncate` and so on. There is `truncate` call in C on linux.

Comment: Sorry! My Bad, it's a C project. Will remove! Specifically will implement this as a method in C

Comment: I added some detailed avout overlap and use

Comment: Better, it's just `head -c-1 file1 file2 ... all_except_last_file > output` followed by `cat last_file >> output`, but I don't know if you want to do it in C (if so, show what have you tried) or using shell.